# Converting a checkbox filter for custom fields to a dropdown

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, filters

I've been scratching my head trying to figure this out for awhile now and was wondering if someone could provide some help. My PHP knowledge isn't the best so I'm working with what I have and it doesn't seem to be enough.

Essentially I wanted to filter custom posts by a custom filter, and managed to come up with a checkbox solution as below from the ACF tutorial:

```
    <div id="search-houses">
    <?php 

    $field = get_field_object('location_choice');
    $values = isset($_GET['location_choice']) ? explode(',', $_GET['location_choice']) : array();

    ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach( $field['choices'] as $choice_value => $choice_label ): ?>
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $choice_value; ?>" <?php if( in_array($choice_value, $values) ): ?>checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> /> <?php echo $choice_label; ?></li>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {

    $('#search-houses').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){

        // vars
        var $ul = $(this).closest('ul'),
            vals = [];

        $ul.find('input:checked').each(function(){

            vals.push( $(this).val() );

        });

        vals = vals.join(",");

        window.location.replace('<?php echo home_url('jobs'); ?>?location_choice=' + vals);

        console.log( vals );

    });

})(jQuery); 
</script>
```

However the client would much prefer a dropdown, so I've been trying to convert it where possible but it's just resulting in a list of dropdowns so I feel I must be doing something wrong in relation to the dropdown and values.

The page can be seen here:

-

Any advice would be much appreciated as I'm pretty stuck!

Thanks

Comment: Make sure not to include the `<select>` part of the dropdown in the `foreach` loop just the `<option>` parts. Then after closing the `foreach` put the closing `</select>`

Comment: Although the example looks like it works ok? Unless I'm looking at the wrong part!